# Environment variable set in the dhcpcd.conf profile is not passed to dhcpcd run hooks

Tags: linux, bash, dhcp, environment-variables

When I set variable in the profile in the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` it is not passed to the hook script:

```
interface eth0
arping 192.168.0.1

profile A1:B2:C3:D4:E5:F6
env enable_proxy=1
```

However, when I put the variable before the profile, like this:

```
interface eth0
arping 192.168.0.1
env enable_proxy=1

profile A1:B2:C3:D4:E5:F6
```

it is suddenly visible inside the hook script. What is going on? The profile is executed correctly - the network configuration inside it is evaluated properly but 
 `env` option has no effect. How can I set environment variables for hook scripts from dhcpcd profile?

Comment: Look over https://www.daemon-systems.org/man/dhcpcd-run-hooks.8.html in case you need to add something there that ensures the `dhcpcd.conf` are effective per your usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, that profiles in DHCPCD are case sensitive i.e. instead of

```
profile A1:B2:C3:D4:E5:F6
```

I should've written profile name in lower case:

```
profile a1:b2:c3:d4:e5:f6
```

Now everything works as it should.